# Change positions of View inside LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am using following layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/lnrLayout_cVideo_LB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_cVideo_LB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".15" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/cVideo_LB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:tag="2" />
       </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVw_cVideo_LB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

So when I click on `VideoView` position of `TextView` should go to top of `VideoView` when I click again, I should restore.

For that I am using following code,

```
video.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(flag_video==0)
            {
                textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float).85);
                relative_LB.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float).15);
                flag_video=1;
                v.invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                relative_LB.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float).15));
                lb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(float).85));

                flag_video=0;
                v.invalidate();
            }
        }
    });
```

But it is not changing its position. I explored solution, I found that I can do it by `View.removeView()` and `View.addView()` method. But for my application purpose I can't use those methods. So anybody suggest me an alternate way??

**Please dont suggest me View.removeView() and view.addView() methods**

Comment: Do you want that the TextView go to the top of the lnrLayout_cVideo_LB?

Comment: What do you mean by "size of TextView should go to top"? What "size"?

Comment: @giacomoni: Ya... Exactly

Comment: @JoelFernandes: Type error... I recorrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are using `onTouch(View v)` method instead of `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method. `onTouch()` method should have tow parameter. 2. Return type of `onTouch()` should be `boolean` type but you are using `void`.
2. Another problem is that you are setting `LayoutParams` to `lb` instead to `textview` in the `else` condition.

Now, replace the following listener code snippet with yours...I think, you will get it right.

```
    video.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (flag_video == 0) {
                textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) .85));
                relative_LB.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) .15));
                flag_video = 1;
                v.invalidate();
            } else {
                relative_LB.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) .85));
                textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) .15));

                flag_video = 0;
                v.invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: I have executed in my project...its working. replace the whole `Listener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of the `RelativeLayout` to `GONE`, it should disappear and the textview go upside, like the following method (when the `flag_video == 0` the textview go up):

```
video.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag_video==0)
        {
            //textview should go upside
            relative_LB.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            flag_video=1;
        }
        else
        {
            relative_LB.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
            flag_video=0;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I use this method `relative_LB.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);` the progress made by `VideoView` will gone and will start from begining. So I can't use this way at all